# Bitcoin transaction stuck for more than a week

Tags: client, unconfirmed-transactions

This transaction is stuck for more than a week, it keep saying in electrum that it is unconfirmed:

https://blockchain.info/tx/622caee53701359b90df448163fcf36f36a5354ada7c01b5f7c1b8f7851080ee

It disappeared from blockchain and other block explorer and it came back with a new date yesterday and today.

I am patient, but seeing that the dates were refreshed is kind of weird.

RBF was not enabled when I sent, and I've put max fees available in my wallet, which is 1 mBTC/KB and it is not enough.

Any idea what I can do?

I tried everything listed here:

[Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046)

And nothing can work in my situation.

Comment: I used all possible tricks, including deleting the transaction offline in my wallet in the JSON file and trying to manually send it with more fees while offline.